# When laptops with Windows 7 will be widely available in the UK?

Tags: windows-7, windows-vista, laptop

My friend is going to buy a laptop very quickly but she wants to have Win7 rather than vista there. She could wait but not too long. When laptops with Windows 7 will be widely available in the UK? Or is it possible to buy a vista laptop now and update it to win7 for free? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Laptops with Windows 7 pre-installed will be available on October 22, 2009 worldwide.

When you buy Windows Vista Home Premium, Business, or Ultimate either as a packaged product or on a qualifying PC you can get a comparable upgrade version of Windows 7 after it’s generally available on October 22, 2009. Qualifying PCs, offer details, and product delivery methods will vary by manufacturer, so check their sites for specifics. If you buy a packaged copy of Windows Vista you can order your upgrade from Microsoft. The Windows 7 Upgrade Option program runs from June 26, 2009 through January 31, 2010. However, individual PC manufacturers may choose to offer the option for a shorter period.

For more information, visit the [Windows 7 Upgrade Option](http://www.microsoft.com/windows/buy/offers/upgrade.aspx) page. For full details, see the [Windows 7 Upgrade Option FAQ](http://www.microsoft.com/windows/buy/offers/upgrade-faq.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Right now, Microsoft are giving all new OEM copies of Vista a voucher code to upgrade to Windows 7 upon release - but I am not sure that counts in your question.

Officially, the launch for Windows 7 is October the 22nd and you will most likely be able to get them then.

Unlike with some other products, on OEM I have not seen any contract or agreement yet, so I can imagine that some people may sell sooner if they get the OEM licences before - but they will probably not be released until a minimum of two days before.